# Android ADB : How to start server ( port 5555 ) without connecting device through USB

Tags: android, adb

Though my ADB over wifi works well, except one small issue, that first time I will have to connect my phone with usb to open port on my mobile `adb start-server 5555`. Is it possible to complete this step without USB ? Do we any option available to start port without USB ?

My phone is not rooted yet, and I have no plan to root it in near future..

Comment: you'll need a rooted phone and a terminal emulator on your phone. Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3623727/5425930

Comment: Thanks, but my phone is not rooted as of now..

Comment: I tried the commands without root (without su) and they didn't work but using root permissions, it definitely works. So your best bet to get it working, is to get root access

Comment: to make `tcp` the default option for `adb` you need to set the `persist.adb.tcp.port` property. it would still require root on most phones though

Answer (score 0):

you either need to have a device connected or an running emulator for using following command:

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

what if you don't have usb cable for some reason?
what to do?
here's a solution.
If you run an android emulator, above command will work but draw back is , it take too much time (few minutes to be specific).
So what's the fastest solution,

Well, install [AnBox](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjigtv73fToAhWC7XMBHcslArUQFjAAegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fanbox.io%2F&usg=AOvVaw3dLbepvSl7Rg6U4B-jhCtZ).
Its also an emulator which opens much faster, within few seconds.
now, you can run above command:

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

to start adb in tcpip mode

use below command to connect to your android phone over wifi

```
adb connect <ip address of android phone>:5555
```

if you want to control it over wifi from laptop use [scrcpy](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiahJPo3vToAhUE93MBHWKcCqMQFjABegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FGenymobile%2Fscrcpy%2Freleases&usg=AOvVaw0TmdOVukq9nAxpWwELFI5t)

```
scrcpy -s <ip address of android phone>:5555
```